# How print Content in div tag using Javascript with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am Developing Report. This is Dynamic report and i want to print. I used below code and it is perfectly working but it doesn't load current css styles in report. how can i add CSS style to final print preview and print out?

```
<button onclick="printcontent('Report-body')">Print</button>

                     <script>
function printcontent(el){
var restorepage=document.body.innerHTML;

document.body.innerHTML=printcontent;
window.print();
document.body.innerHTML=printcontent;
}
        </script>
```

Report develop in div tag

Comment: I guess you might need to use inline styles to print it and I believe you are right now having external stylesheets implied!!

Comment: use a style tag

Comment: Why can't you just print it from the current page and use a print css file in a normal link tag?

Comment: Actually unable to use style tag because i have used bootstrap framework...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
 var divContents = document.body.innerHTML;
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>Title</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
```

Comment: unable to use this according to my requirement because attached bootstrap files with here